# File read using "open()" vs "with open()"

Tags: python, performance, file-io

I know there are plenty of articles and questions answered regarding reading files in python. But still I'm wondering what made python to have multiple ways to do the same task. Simply what I want to know is, what is the performance impact of using these two methods?

Comment: THis question has already been asked in SO

Comment: Context managers was introduced much later than pure `open()` method. You can measure performance with `timeit.timeit()` method. `with` context manager simply releases resources on any failure, so you do not have to write explicit `finally` clause.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Using `with` statement is not for performance gain, I do not think there are any performance gains or loss associated with using `with` statement, as long as, you perform the same cleanup activity that using `with` statement would perform automatically.

When you use `with` statement with `open` function, you do not need to close the file at the end, because `with` would automatically close it for you.

Also, `with` statement is not just for openning files, with is used in conjuction with context managers. Basically, if you have an object that you want to make sure it is cleaned once you are done with it or some kind of errors occur, you can define it as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) and `with` statement will call its `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods on entry to and exit from the with block. According to [PEP 0343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) -

> This PEP adds a new statement "`with`" to the Python language to make it possible to factor out standard uses of try/finally statements.
>
> In this PEP, context managers provide `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods that are invoked on entry to and exit from the body of the with statement.

Also, performance testing of using `with` and not using it -

```
In [14]: def foo():
   ....:     f = open('a.txt','r')
   ....:     for l in f:
   ....:         pass
   ....:     f.close()
   ....:

In [15]: def foo1():
   ....:     with open('a.txt','r') as f:
   ....:         for l in f:
   ....:             pass
   ....:

In [17]: %timeit foo()
The slowest run took 41.91 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000 loops, best of 3: 186 µs per loop

In [18]: %timeit foo1()
The slowest run took 206.14 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000 loops, best of 3: 179 µs per loop

In [19]: %timeit foo()
The slowest run took 202.51 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000 loops, best of 3: 180 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit foo1()
10000 loops, best of 3: 193 µs per loop

In [21]: %timeit foo1()
10000 loops, best of 3: 194 µs per loop
```

Comment: "When you use with statement with open function, you do not need to close the file at the end, because with would automatically close it for you." I never knew about this! Which part of the Python documentation mentions it?