# Python -- TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, formatter, nonetype

Tried combining target.write into a single line with formatters and am now receiving an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
```

Now:

```
target.write("%s, %s, %s") % (line1, line2, line3)
```

same error when using:

```
target.write("%r, %r, %r") % (line1, line2, line3)
```

## Full file below:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write("%s, %s, %s") % (line1, line2, line3)

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meant to write

```
target.write("%s, %s, %s" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

You are attempting a modulus operation on the return value of `target.write` and a tuple. `target.write` will be returning `None` so

```
None % <tuple-type>
```

makes no sense and is not a supported operation, whereas for a string `%` has an overloaded meaning for formatting the string.

Answer (score 1):

@Paul Rooney explains the problem with your code in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059505/21945).

The preferred method of performing string formatting is to use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
target.write("{}, {}, {}".format(line1, line2, line3))
```

Or you could use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to add the separator:

```
target.write(', '.join((line1, line2, line3)))
```

Or you even use the Python 3 `print` function in Python 2:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print(line1, line2, line3, sep=', ', file=target, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Life is easy:

```
>>> with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
...     line1 = 'asdasdasd'
...     line2 = 'sfbdfbdfgdfg'
...     f.write(str(x) + '\n')
...     f.write(str(y))
```

The parameter inside `write()` function must be a string, and you can concatenate 2 strings by using the "+" operator.

Notice that I use `with open(...) as f` to open a file. The reason is with `with open()`, you don't need to close the file by yourself, it will automatically close when you reach out the `with open()` block.

More info: [File read using "open()" vs "with open()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334061/file-read-using-open-vs-with-open/31334226#31334226)