# How do I print out results on a separate line after converting them from a set to a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently trying to compare to text files, to see if they have any words in common in both files.

The text files are as

```
ENGLISH.TXT
circle
table
year
competition
```

```
FRENCH.TXT
bien
competition
merci
air
table
```

My current code is getting them to print, Ive removed all the unnessecary squirly brackets and so on, but I cant get them to print on different lines.

```
List = open("english.txt").readlines()
List2 = open("french.txt").readlines()

anb = set(List) & set(List2)
anb = str(anb)

anb = (str(anb)[1:-1])
anb = anb.replace("'","")
anb = anb.replace(",","")
anb = anb.replace('\\n',"")

print(anb)
```

The output is expected to separate both results onto new lines.

```
Currently Happening: 
Competition Table
```

```
Expected:
Competition
Table
```

Thanks in advance!
- Xphoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I'd suggest you to try two things as a good practice:
1) Use "with" for opening files

```
with open('english.txt', 'r') as englishfile, open('french.txt', 'r') as frenchfile:
##your python operations for the file
```

2) Try to use the "f-String" opportunity if you're using Python 3:

```
print(f"Hello\nWorld!")
```

[File read using "open()" vs "with open()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334061/file-read-using-open-vs-with-open)
This post explains very well why to use the "with" statement :)
And additionally to the f-strings if you want to print out variables do it like this:

```
 print(f"{variable[index]}\n variable2[index2]}")
```

Should print out:
Hello and World! in seperate lines

**Here is one solution including converting between sets and lists:**

```
with open('english.txt', 'r') as englishfile, open('french.txt', 'r') as frenchfile:

   english_words = englishfile.readlines()
   english_words = [word.strip('\n') for word in english_words]
   french_words = frenchfile.readlines()
   french_words = [word.strip('\n') for word in french_words]

   anb = set(english_words) & set(french_words)
   anb_list = [item for item in anb]
   for item in anb_list:
       print(item)
```

**Here is another solution by keeping the words in lists:**

```
with open('english.txt', 'r') as englishfile, open('french.txt', 'r') as frenchfile:

   english_words = englishfile.readlines()
   english_words = [word.strip('\n') for word in english_words]
   french_words = frenchfile.readlines()
   french_words = [word.strip('\n') for word in french_words]

   for english_word in english_words:
       for french_word in french_words:
           if english_word == french_word:
               print(english_word)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Some great tips.

Comment: No problem hope you can grasp the code - do you know about list comprehension? works like this `[what should happen with the ITEM for ITEM in LIST]`