# Is there any advantage to using 'open()' rather than 'with open()'?

Tags: python, file, with-statement

I know that it is a lot better to use

```
with open(...)...
```

but I was wondering if there is ever a case where using

```
open(...)
```

has any advantage in any situation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. `with open(...)` manages the file descriptor for you so once the with block is done python automatically closes the file descriptor for you. However in some scenarios it might be more performant / necessary  to keep the file descriptor. A simple example would be a function that opens a file and writes a header line and passes the file descriptor back:

```
def open_and_write_header(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.write('This is my header')
    return f

file_desc = open_and_write_header('testfile.txt')
file_desc.write('This is my tail')
file_desc.close()
```

Whereas if we use the `with` syntax:

```
def open_and_write_header(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('This is my header')
        return f

file_desc = open_and_write_header('testfile.txt')
file_desc.write('This is my tail')
file_desc.close()
```

we get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 7, in <module>
    file_desc.write('This is my tail')
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 0):

`file = open(...)` requires you to close that file again with `file.close()`. with open(...) does this for you. Else there's no difference.

Comment: There is a difference! Look at this post [File read using "open()" vs "with open()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334061/file-read-using-open-vs-with-open). What if you open a file using `open`, and then an error occurs? The file will remain opened! When using `with` it **will** close the file

Answer (score 0):

within the block of code opened by `with`, file is open, and can be read from freely. However, when Python exits from the `with` block, the file is automatically closed.

so if you might do a lot of stuff with the same file in your program (if you have some user interface program with some calculations, for example) you might want to keep file open instead of closing and reopening it again and again.